# Google Chrome's empty Cache and Hard Reload does not empty text

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, web-hosting

On chrome, the text on our wordpress contact form [page](https://mostmarv.com/contact) does not update when I do the following:

1. Enter developer mode `f12`
2. In developer mode, select `network` and click disable cache
3. Right click reload and select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`

If I go to firefox, the changes can be seen, so it is not a hosting issue.  Our host is namecheap.

This is really annoying, does anyone know how I can force chrome to discover the new text?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to open the page in a private tab. This is not actually a solution, but for testing purposes it could do the trick.